# Spinner OnItemSelected Listener not working

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I am populating an ArrayList dynamically, and I added a listener to update a spinner with those values. The problem is, when I select an item in the spinner, no action is being done. The item I press, isn't even being selected in the list. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Main Activity

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterType;
    adapterType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AvailableHostListString);
    hostNameSpinner.setAdapter(adapterType);

    hostNameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            EditText hostNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hostNameEditText);
            hostNameEditText.setText(item);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Detected Spinner Selection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

activity_main.xml

```
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/hostNameSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Comment: Interestingly, as a work-around... If I add a value to the arraylist; then it will work fine

Comment: That is, add a value to the arraylist before I initialize the listener.. then it works fine.

Comment: maybe u just need `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();`